# Hide the scroll bar but it still can scroll

Tags: html, css, reactjs, next.js, chakra-ui

This's my code:

```
<HStack width={"full"} overflowX={"auto"}>
   <Button>1</Button>
   <Button>2</Button>
   <Button>3</Button>
   <Button>4</Button>
   <Button>5</Button>
</HStack>
```

I've try overflow={"hidden"} for a Htack is the parent of this HStack but nothing happened